# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 - "file not found service/random" for Mobile Web environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I have implement Encrypted Cache in my application. When testing is in the Mobile Web environment using the mobile browser in my device, I get the following exception:

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not
>   found: /apps/services/BMA_app/apps/services/random
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found:
>   /apps/services/BMA_app/apps/services/random   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:496)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:191)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
>     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
>     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)  [project BMA_app] SRVE0190E:
>   File not found: /apps/services/BMA_app/apps/services/random

When testing in other environments, the error does not occur.

**EDIT**: I just saw that, this service allows to get a key for encrypted cache. It allows to open it. Given that, the service is 404, I got a failure for opening cache.

Moreover, the Worklight Console gives me this URL for mobile web app:

```
http:/my-server:port/BMA_app/apps/services/www/BMA_app/mobilewebapp/
```

the app tries to get a key for encrypted cache and send to `http:/my-server:port/BMA_app/apps/services/BMA_app/apps/services/random`

^ 404 error

If we cut this previous url to `http://my-server:port/BMA_app/apps/services/random`, it works.

It seems that in the URL "BMA_app/apps/services" is repeated twice instead of once.
Why and how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have encountered a defect.

Testing in 6.1.0.1 with the Encrypted Cache sample project and adding to it the Mobile Web environment, if you use the link provided by the "Get App URL" button - then when you try to "open cache" from the app, it will fail with `status code 10`. This status code means that the app was unable to connect to the Worklight Server's Random generator service.

Indeed, when inspecting the console log, the app tries to connect to the following URL, where "EncryptedCache/apps/services" is repeated twice...:

```
http://192.168.1.101:10080/EncryptedCache/apps/services/EncryptedCache/apps/services/random?isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.18816258828155696
```

There is no workaround for this defect as it is the framework that generates the URL.

I have opened a defect.
If you are an IBM customer or business partner and require a fix, you can open a PMR and mention this Stackoverflow question.

Moving forward, the fix will be available in an iFix and any future fixpack released.